# access to extraFiles electron-builder from packaged asar app electron

Tags: electron, electron-builder, winston

I have an electron app that run perfectly into a dev environment with logs engine that write into file (with winston.js).

*The structure of the project is this* :

[image]

*When I run electron-builder for packaging my app I have this struture* :

[image]

- my app.asar file is into Resources directory
- my logs files are into data/logs

*In dev environment I access to logs file with this winston config* :

```
new winston.transports.File({filename: 'data/logs/error.log', level: 'error'})
```

But this specific path config only run into dev mode. And I don't find a good path for targetting the logs files in prod environment.

**What kind of path I need to use in prod environment for targetting files out of Resources directory (or root of Contents directory installed application) ?**

**What is the best pratices for managing logs with electron app ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting the resources and `extraFiles` paths in a packaged app as described in the [electron-builder docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents#extrafiles) you can use [`process.resourcesPath`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/process#processresourcespath-readonly)

```js
const getResourcesPath = () => {
  return process.resourcesPath;
};

const getExtraFilesPath = () => {
  return path.join(process.resourcesPath, '..'); // go up one directory
};
```

For logs, Electron provides a path for this purpose which you can check using [`app.getPath`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname)

```js
app.getPath('logs');
```

By default, this will be `~/Library/Logs/YourAppName` on macOS, and inside the `userData` directory on Linux and Windows

You can change this default path using [`app.setAppLogsPath`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetapplogspathpath) if needed

Most Electron apps store logs in the default location

Comment: Useful response ! It work perfectly and I understand how find any other path.